# Get kafka record timestamp by partition and offset

Tags: apache-kafka

There are many threads describing how to get records from Kafka starting from the specified timestamp.
So I think Kafka 'knows' timestamp for every record it stores.
I need to get the timestamp for the record with a specified partition and offset. Is it possible?

An information system put the wrong data to Kafka (incorrect product id in client's order) and I need to analyze log files to find out the cause. It would be much easier to do it knowing the timestamp of that record.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord has a method called timestamp().
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I can get it programmatically. But I ned it in the server console. I want to get timestamp of that record without writing any tool specifically for this task.

Comment: You may use "--property print.timestamp=true" in kafka-console-consumer to display the time stamp of message.

Comment: That's what I've been looking for. Thanks, @guobiao-mo